# Confusion with the derivative of curves

Tags: manifolds, proof-explanation

The following proof is from Lee's book.

[image]

I did not understand the first and third equalities, and so I now believe that I did not understand derivatives correctly: what is $\gamma'(t_0)$? It does not make sense for it to be $\gamma_*(t_0)$ as I would initially assume, because it would act on elements of the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}$ and not on real-valued maps like $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of $\gamma'(t_0)$ is on page 75* -- it's given by
$$
\gamma'(t_0) = \gamma_* \left( \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t_0}\right)\in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M.
$$
The derivation of the equalities you're worried about appears later on that same page.

---

*Note that the OP's excerpt is from the first edition of my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. The analogous material in the second edition appears on pages 69 and 208.